# How do I make a UWP Count down timer control that allows you to input a time limit

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

How do I make A timer flyout that shows 0:00 and let's you select seconds and minutes? I'm trying to work with the `timePicker` but I can't figure it out. I only shows a clock with a time like 12:00 AM
What I am looking for is almost identical to a `timePicker` set to the `24Hour ClockIdentifier` except that when you click on the hours the flyout shows numbers from 0 to 99 instead of 0 to 24 and if you click on the minutes the flyout shows numbers from 0 to 99 instead of 0 to 60.

Comment: what exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ComboBox` and populate the values yourself using a `List` for minutes and hours.

Xaml:
`<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Hours} />`

C#:
`public List<int> Hours { get { return Enumerable.Range(0, 99).ToList(); } }`

Edit: realised you wanted 0 - 99 not 24 as I had set in the Range.